# Generic no backup on Revert for mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How can I make a global setting that will make the revert command ignore backup creation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make an alias in .hgrc

```
[alias]
revert = revert --no-backup

# or better make another name for this command
drop = revert --no-backup
```

Comment: You're right that it's better to create a new command rather than set params on an old one.  You never know when some application that calls mercurial from the command line relies on default beahavior.  IDE plugins certainly do.